# Entity framework is making the id null on insert

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm getting the following error when I try to insert a new row in one of my relational tables. I have the following two models:

```
public class CompanyCredit
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int creditId { get; set; }

    public int planCredit { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PlanCreditExpirationDate { get; set; }

}
```

And

```
public class CompanyInformation
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Company Name:")]
    public string companyName { get; set; }

    public string timeZone { get; set; }

    //navigation Properties       
    public virtual CompanyCredit Credits { get; set; }
}
```

And this Relation in the dbContext

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyInformation>().HasOptional(e => e.Credits);
```

I'm trying to add a record inside CompanyCredit table like so:

```
if (_company.Credits == null)
{
   var _credits = new CompanyCredit();
   _credits.planCredit = 200;
   _credits.PlanCreditExpirationDate = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1);

   _company.Credits = _credits;
   repo.InsertOrUpdate(_company, User.Identity.Name);
 }
```

And Finally Insert or update just marks Company as changed and _credit as added like so:

```
 _db.Entry(_credits).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
 _db.Entry(Company).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
 _db.SaveChanges();
```

When this runs I get the following Error that I just can't seem to find the reason to.

```
 Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'creditId', table 'Project.dbo.CompanyCredits'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

The statement has been terminated.

Thank in advanced for your help.

Comment: Check the id column in the database, it needs to be explicitly configured to generate the identity values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem was in the attribute `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` this should have been `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` 
I thought I would post this so others might benefit from it.

Comment: Those mean exactly the same thing to the compiler. That cannot possibly have made any difference.

Comment: And I'm fairly confident it will continue working if you change it back, that the reason it started working is really something else that you forgot you changed. :)

Comment: I tried this approach and still have the error. I have posted my question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150890/table-not-incrementing-after-an-insert-in-asp-net-mvc/45153161?noredirect=1#comment77324329_45153161 and there seem to be no resolution to this yet. H

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try reversing the order of entity state modification, just before the saveChanges call

```
 _db.Entry(Company).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
 _db.Entry(_credits).State = System.Data.EntityState.Added;
 _db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. I tried it and its giving me the same error

Comment: The first line _db.Entry(Company).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified; does the code compile with it?, shouldnt it be _db.Entry(_company).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified

Comment: hey sorry, yeah it does as those are sitting inside the repository and the `Company` is being passed in as a parameter.